# "Арендую", "сниму" или "сниму в аренду" (гараж)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно пишется?
"Арендую", "сниму" или "сниму в аренду" (гараж)

Answer (score 1):

Арендую - деловой стиль.

Сниму гараж - разговорный стиль.

Сниму в аренду - нарушение сочетаемости,контаминация,к тому же и плеоназм, действительно: сниму(что?) = возьму (как?куда?)в аренду(антонимы сдам в аренду, возьму в собственность)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, верными будут варианты "арендую" или "возьму в аренду", а вот "сниму в аренду" попахивает плеоназмом.